# How to set up a time counter between two clicks in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a VBA code that allows me to calculate the time ellapsed between two clicks/buttons.

Here is the scenario I'm looking for :

1. I select an empty cell in the column Time
2. I click on the START button (to start the counter)
3. I click on the STOP  button (to stop the counter)
4. The ellapsed time (in the format "hh:mm:dd") has to be put in the selected cell in step 1

##### Expected output :

[image]

I started making a code for the `START` button but I don't know how the one's for the `STOP` button.

```
Sub CalculateTime()

Dim startTime As Double
Dim TimeElapsed As String

  startTime = Timer

  TimeElapsed = Format((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
  
  ActiveCell.Value = TimeElapsed

End Sub
```

Do you have any suggestions, please ?
Any help will be appreciated !

##### EDIT :

Here is the code of my two subs :

```
Sub StartButton()

Call CalculateTime(True)

End Sub

'**************************************

Sub StopButton()

ActiveCell.Value = CalculateTime(False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to tackle this. One way is to use a global variable (startTime) which is set in your Start button click event. Your Stop button then executes your method and (sans the `startTime = Time` line obviously).

But I prefer to avoid *global* variables, so therefore you could rewrite your `Sub` as a `Function` and call it twice. Once from the Start button: `Call CalculateTime(True)`. And once from the Stop button: `ActiveCell.Value = CalculateTime(False)`

```
Function CalculateTime(ByVal bolStart As Boolean) As String

    ' Declaring a local variable as Static preserves their value between calls
    ' of the method.
    Static startTime As Double

    If bolStart = True Then
    ' This is the start of the measurement, we simply store the time
       startTime = Timer
    Else
    ' This is the end of the measurement, so we calculate the time elapsed
    ' and return it as a string.
        CalculateTime = Format$((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Hel O'Ween for your help. I replaced `End Sub` in your code with `End Function`, created two subs for my two buttons, clicked on start, waited for 10 seconds but finally I got `00:00:00`. Can you tell me why, please ?

Comment: Add the code of those to subs to your initial question. Sorry for the `End Sub` oversight. Typical copy&paste error :-)

Comment: No worries. I added the two subs codes in my initial question. Check it out!

Comment: In `Sub StopButton()` you do a call to `Call CalculateTime(True)` again right *before* `Call CalculateTime(False)`. `Call CalculateTime(True)` always *starts/resets* the stop watch, `Call CalculateTime(False)` *stops* the stop watch and returns the elapsed time as a formatted string.

Comment: My bad ! Thank you so much @Hel O'Ween. I removed `Call CalculateTime(True)` from my `StopButton()` sub and it worked.